# How to copy a salesforce org into a new one

Tags: data-migration

I want to copy one of my org into a new org because I need to test my changes in one test org before pushing the data to the "official" one. To be clear, I need to copy the data and the metadata. I figured out how to copy the metadata using ant, but I still can't find an elegant way to copy the data itself.

I am looking for a one-click migration tool that will copy all the cases/account/custom objects, knowledge articles etc.. from the official org to my test org.

Anyone knows a good tool that will allow me to do that? If not, do you know the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this would be a [sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=create_test_instance.htm&language=en). I suggest a full sandbox.

> **Full Sandbox**
>
> Full sandboxes copy your entire production organization
>   and all its data, including standard and custom object records,
>   documents, and attachments. You can refresh a Full sandbox every 29
>   days.

Unfortunately, this requires more licensing, but it is a 1 button tool that will copy all of your metadata and data into a separate test org. It is exactly what you are looking for I believe.

---

If you aren't using a sandbox, you will have to use the [Data Loader](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader) (for data) and the [Force.com Migration Tool](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Migration_Tool_Guide) (for metadata). However, that isn't a one click solution. The properly load in objects with the data loader, specifically objects with relationships to other objects, it can get a bit tricky.